# C++ cin char read symbol-by-symbol

Tags: c++, stream, char, cin

I need to read symbol-by-symbol. But I don't know how to read until end of input. As exemple test system will cin>>somecharvariable m times. I have to read symbol-by-symbol all characters. Only m times. How I can do it?

Comment: Try putting it into a string.

Comment: Are you reading until end of input, *m* times, or are you reading *m* amount of symbols?

Comment: or look into `istream::get(char* buffer, size_t len, char delimiter)` and `istream::read(char* buffer, size_t len)` if you want all bytes including whitespace and newlines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want formatted input character-by-character, do this:

```
char c;
while (infile >> c)
{
  // process character c
}
```

If you want to read raw bytes, do this:

```
char b;
while (infile.get(b))
// while(infile.read(&b, 1)   // alternative, compare and profile
{
  // process byte b
}
```

In either case, `infile` should be of type `std::istream &` or similar, such as a file or `std::cin`.

Comment: For reading raw bytes (symbos), the `cin.read` method is usually more efficient, at the very minimum it uses less function calls.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Thanks, I thought about that, too -- I added the alternative version.

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to read one character at a time until you have read them all, and none of them is necessarily the best.

Personally, I’d go with the following code:

```
char c;
while (cin.get(c)) {
    // Process c here.
}
```

If you only need to read `m` characters, consider using a `for` loop:

```
char c;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m && cin.get(c); ++i) {
    // Process c here.
}
```

This runs the loop as long as two conditions are fulfilled: (1) less than `m` characters have been read, and (2) there are still characters to read.

However, both solutions have a drawback: they are relatively inefficient. It’s more efficient to read the `m` characters in one go.

So first allocate a big enough buffer to store `m` chars and then attempt to read them:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(m);
cin.read(&buffer[0], m);
unsigned total_read = cin.gcount();
```

Notice the last line – this will tell you whether `m` characters have been actually read.

Comment: This solution doesn't read m amount of symbols or it doesn't repeat reading until EOF, m times.

Comment: +1 for the update, especially covering the EOF case in the `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch;
    unsigned m = 10;
    while (cin && m--) {
        cin.read(&ch, sizeof(ch));
        cout << ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the cast from a `char*` to a `char*`?

Comment: This solution doesn't read *m* amount of symbols or it doesn't repeat reading until EOF, *m* times.

Comment: @TravisGockel There is no reason to do so. Fixed :)