# How can I make my program finish when there is no more std input in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on an algorithm, and I am asked to print "QUIT" when there is no more input to the program.

I am using

```
char c;
while(c = getchar()){...}
```

because I need to look for `'\n'` characters and numbers.

So I copy the sample input and paste it on my program's to test it, but it keeps waiting for another input and therefore I get a *time limit exceeded* when I submit it.

PS: I can't use multithreading.

Comment: How do you know if there is more input? I might just consider pressing another key if you just wait another second.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop when `getchar()` returns `EOF`, like this:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {...}
```

Note that `c` needs to be declared an `int`, not a `char`.

To make your program more C++-like, use operator `>>` instead of `getchar` in a loop, like this:

```
char c;
while (cin >> c) {...}
```

Comment: I use getchar() because using cin it doesn't detect the extra '\n'

Comment: @Carlos I see. Then `cin.get(c)` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7679402/335858) is better.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` returns an int, not a char.
In particular, it returns EOF on end of file, and EOF is typically -1. So if you store that in a char, it will never compare equal to EOF.

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading in from a file?  If so, `getchar()` will return EOF: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/

so

```
    int c=getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {...}
```

should work.

Comment: You're on the right track, but this code snippet doesn't change the value of `c`. You need to either add `c = getchar();` before the end of the loop body or change the `while` statement to `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I just assumed that he would update the variable at the end of the loop, but it's always good to remember that sort of thing.